# build resources based on variable count

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecr

may I ask if there is a way to build an aws resource using **Terraform v0.14.10** base from the count of the defined variables and use the name of the variable as part of the name of the created ECR resource. Its like I want to build ECR repo and it should be 3 of them coz of the variables I used has 3 and use the name as the repo name like as below:

**Results of ECR build creation**

```
app1.repo
pogi2.repo
panget3.repo
```

**Terraform Code:**

**MY.TF**

```
variable RESOURCE_NAME { type = map }

locals {
  RESOURCE_NAME  = "${var.app-name}-repo"
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "myrepo" {
  name = local.RESOURCE_NAME
}
```

**VAR.tfvars**

```
app-name = [ "app1", "pogi2", "panget3" ]
```

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want to do? Any actual TF code example?

Comment: Marcin - I just want to build 3 separate ECR (defined in var.tfvars). Each of the  variable names from "app-names" will be assigned to the name of the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "myrepo" {
  for_each = toset(var.app-name)
  name = "${each.key}.repo"
}
```